# Why does my raspberry pi zero wifi seem to shut off?

Tags: pi-zero-w

I'm using a Raspberry Pi Zero Wifi as an ad blocker (pi-hole) in Wi-Fi mode. My problem is that it seems to shut off. It stops blocking advertisements, I am unable to ping it and I am unable to access the web server with the ip address. People have suggested turning off the wifi power saving mode. I tried that with instructions from https://www.modmypi.com/blog/disable-wifi-power-management. The problem still continues until I restart the Raspberry Pi. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you powering the Pi?

Comment: I am using a 5v 2amp power supply.

Comment: I would carefully measure the power at the gpio pins to rule out a bad power supply or cable.

Comment: I get 5.45 volts.

Comment: Is there something I can judge from this number?

Comment: You can assume that the power supply and cable are OK and not likely the cause of the problem